# How to calculate conditional probability of all possible pairs of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, probability

I have following boolean dataframe in pandas:

```
      Cat  Dog  Mouse
Alex   1    0     1
Lola   0    0     1
Bob    1    1     1
```

Each cell contains true/false saying whether someone has animal or not.
I would like to get dataframe which contains conditional probability of each pair of animals where rows dictate condition.

```
      Cat  Dog  Mouse
Cat    1   50%    1
Dog    1    1     1
Mouse 66%  33%    1
```

Is there fast way of doing this in pandas? If yes, then how?

Comment: What do you mean by *Is there fast way of doing this in pandas?* . You can say some method is faster only comparison to another method. Can you show us what you tried? Then only someone can suggest if there is a faster approach.

Comment: @ThePyGuy by fast I meant "oneliner" kind of fast

Comment: You got it wrong, onliner doesn't necessarily mean faster approach, it just means lesser code.

Comment: @ThePyGuy I understand what "fast" means. Calling it "fast" just was a shorthand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dot product between the df and the transposed df and calculate the rank as percentage:

```
df.T.dot(df).rank(axis=1,method='dense',pct=True).round(3)
```

---

```
         Cat    Dog  Mouse
Cat    1.000  0.500    1.0
Dog    1.000  1.000    1.0
Mouse  0.667  0.333    1.0
```

Comment: Now that I look at it. It doesn't work if there were 4 or more owners of animals. Output should be 3x3 but it's 4x4 with 4 owners

Comment: @ArekŻyłkowski Try now? Edited the approach a bit

Comment: It seems to be right now, thank you again!

Comment: @ArekŻyłkowski Glad to know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a "oneliner" solution using pandas....Have a look at `pandas.crosstab`:

```
pandas.crosstab(index, columns, values=None, rownames=None, colnames=None, aggfunc=None, margins=False, margins_name='All', dropna=True, normalize=False)
```